# Piping an output to two different command with or statement

Tags: bash

I'm piping a code to python with this:

```
echo "print 'hello'" | python &
```

But in some cases, I need to pipe it to `sudo python` but I won't know if it will be necessary. So I need an `or` condition. If `python` throws error, it should be piped to `sudo python`. For example:

```
echo "print 'hello'" | python & | sudo python &
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can pipe into a conditional.

```
echo "print 'hello'" |
#### BROKEN
if python; then
    : nothing
else
    sudo python
fi
```

The problem here is that the first `python` probably eats all the input and then the `sudo python` won't receive any input from the pipeline.  One way to handle that is with a temporary file.

```
tempfile=$(mktemp -t) || exit
# Clean up if interrupted or when done
trap 'rm -f "$tempfile"' EXIT ERROR HUP INT TERM
echo "print 'hello'" >"$tempfile"
python <"$tempfile" || sudo python <"$tempfile"
```

Comment: Save it in a script file and call the file "oneline"? Obviously don't forget to `chmod +x` the file and making sure the directory is on your `PATH`. Syntactically, all of that can be typed on a single line by exchanging newlines with semicolons (but then probably remove the `trap` and instead just `rm` the temporary file at the end unconditionally ... Oh and the comment obviously has to be removed as well).